# Print the first Fibonacci number which has a certain length

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, user-input, fibonacci

So I'm basically just trying to figure out how I can get this program to print out the first Fibonacci number with the same amount of numbers in length as the number that the user has input. The Fibonacci counting portion of this works fine, I'm just struggling to understand how I can print out a number that corresponds correctly. Having problems specifically understanding why this line of code:

```
print(str(result[user]))
```

does not work and what I need to do to make it work.

```
def fibonacci():
    previous_num, result = 0, 1
    user = input('please enter the length of the fibonacci number you would like to see')
    while True:
        previous_num, result = result, previous_num + result
        print(result)
        print(str(result[user]))


fibonacci()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's examine the line you're stuck on:

```
print(str(result[user]))
```

What the code is trying to do here is access the `user` attribute of the variable `result`, convert it to a `str`, and then print it. It's not working, because the variable `result` is an integer, and doesn't have anything which can be accessed using square brackets.

Possibly what you want to do is print the length of the `result` variable. This can be done by converting `result` to a string using `str`, and finding its length using `len`.

```
print(len(str(result)))
```

This, combined with the previous line, `print(result)`, will print out the Fibonacci number, along with the length of the number in digits.

**For example:**

```
1
1
2
1
3
1
5
1
8
1
13
2
...
```

This isn't what we want - we want our function to return the first Fibonacci number that has the amount of digits that our user inputs. To do this, we need to edit our `while` condition to the following:

```
while len(str(result)) < user:
```

So we check if the length of the `result` is less than the length our user asked for, and if not, we compute the next Fibonacci number. If it is, we break out of the while loop, and we can return `result`. Now we can remove the print statements as well.

The final thing left to do is wrap our `input` function with `int`, to convert the number the user inputs to an integer, so we can compare it with the length of `result`.

Our final program is then as follows:

**Code:**

```
def fibonacci():
    previous_num, result = 0, 1
    user = int(input('please enter the length of the fibonacci number you would like to see: '))
    while len(str(result)) < user:
        previous_num, result = result, previous_num + result
    return result

print(fibonacci())
```

**Output:**

```
please enter the length of the fibonacci number you would like to see: 10
1134903170
```

**Alternatively:** @Sadap in comments

```
def fibonacci():
    previous_num, result = 0, 1
    user = int(input('please enter the length of the fibonacci number you would like to see: '))
    min_num = 10**(user-1)
    while result < min_num:
        previous_num, result = result, previous_num + result
    return result

print(fibonacci())
```

Comment: good answer, but after the input, write `min_num = 10**(user-1)` then the while condition is `result < min_num` that solution is much faster than converting every possible result to a str just to get the length